# Iso macro in Scala

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, scalaz, scala-macros, scalaz7

If I want to implicitly convert two objects from one to another, is there anyway to do this using something like an Iso macro?

For example, if I have this:

```
implicit def listToMap[A, B](l: List[(A, B)]): Map[A, B] = l.toMap
implicit def mapToList[A, B](m: Map[A, B]): List[(A, B)] = m.toList
```

I want to simply write:

```
implicit def[A, B] listMapIso = Iso[List[(A, B)], Map[A, B]] {_.toMap, _.toList}
```

Note: As noted below, I plan to use this in my web framework where I convert my database models to middleware/front-end models.

Comment: I don't think you really want to implicitly convert between types like this, especially the types in your example. Each implicit conversion you write is a hole you are creating in the typechecker. Example: Imagine after a refactoring you are accidentally passing List to functions which takes Map. `val m: Map[String, String] = List("a" -> "A", "a" -> "a")`

Comment: That was just an example... I plan to use this to convert to and from models that come out from my database and my app-layer models

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be confusing several different concepts. Iso, implicit conversions, and macros are all quite different from each other.

We can certainly define an equivalent of Iso for parameterized types, though the syntax becomes a little more cumbersome:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._
case class BiIso[F[_, _], G[_, _]](left: F ~~> G,
  right: G ~~> F)

type PairList[A, B] = List[(A, B)]
val listToMap = new (PairList ~~> Map) {
  def apply[A, B](l: PairList[A, B]) = l.toMap
}
val mapToList = new (Map ~~> PairList) {
  def apply[A, B](m: Map[A, B]) = m.toList
}

val listMapIso = BiIso(listToMap, mapToList)
```

We can of course make parts of this implicit, though this is an orthogonal concern. We can build the BiIso implicitly:

```
implicit val listToMap = new (PairList ~~> Map) {
  def apply[A, B](l: PairList[A, B]) = l.toMap
}
implicit val mapToList = new (Map ~~> PairList) {
  def apply[A, B](m: Map[A, B]) = m.toList
}

implicit def biIso[F[_, _], G[_, _]](implicit left: F ~~> G, right: G ~~> F) =
  BiIso(left, right)

implicitly[BiIso[PairList, Map]]
```

And we can make any BiIso act as an implicit conversion, though I would recommend against it. The only tricky part is guiding the type inference correctly. This is most of the way there, but for some reason the GAB parameter isn't inferred (a correction would be very welcome):

```
sealed trait BiAny[F[_, _]] {}
object BiAny {
  implicit def any[F[_, _]] = new BiAny[F] {}
}

sealed trait ApplyBiIso[FAB, GAB] {
  type A1
  type B1
  type F[_, _]
  type G[_, _]
  type Required = BiIso[F, G]

  val unapplyL: Unapply2[BiAny, FAB] {
    type A = A1; type B = B1;
    type M[C, D] = F[C, D]
  }
  val unapplyR: Unapply2[BiAny, GAB] {
    type A = A1; type B = B1;
    type M[C, D] = G[C, D]
  }

  def liftBI(bi: Required): Iso[FAB, GAB] =
    Iso({ fab: FAB =>
      val f: F[A1, B1] = Leibniz.witness(unapplyL.leibniz)(fab)
      val g: G[A1, B1] = bi.left(f)
      Leibniz.witness(Leibniz.symm[⊥, ⊤, GAB, G[A1, B1]](unapplyR.leibniz))(g): GAB
    },
      { gab: GAB =>
        val g: G[A1, B1] = Leibniz.witness(unapplyR.leibniz)(gab)
        val f: F[A1, B1] = bi.right(g)
        Leibniz.witness(Leibniz.symm[⊥, ⊤, FAB, F[A1, B1]](unapplyL.leibniz))(f): FAB
      }
    )
}

object ApplyBiIso {
  implicit def forFG[FAB, A2, B2, GAB, A3, B3](
    implicit u1: Unapply2[BiAny, FAB] { type A = A2; type B = B2 },
    u2: Unapply2[BiAny, GAB] { type A = A3; type B = B3 }) = new ApplyBiIso[FAB, GAB] {
    type A1 = A2
    type B1 = B2
    type F[C, D] = u1.M[C, D]
    type G[C, D] = u2.M[C, D]

    //Should do the conversion properly with Leibniz but I can't be bothered
    val unapplyL = u1.asInstanceOf[Unapply2[BiAny, FAB] {
      type A = A1; type B = B1;
      type M[C, D] = F[C, D]
    }]
    val unapplyR = u2.asInstanceOf[Unapply2[BiAny, GAB] {
      type A = A1; type B = B1;
      type M[C, D] = G[C, D]
    }]
  }
  type Aux[FAB, GAB, Required1] = ApplyBiIso[FAB, GAB] { type Required = Required1 }
  def apply[FAB, GAB](implicit abi: ApplyBiIso[FAB, GAB]): Aux[FAB, GAB, abi.Required] = abi
}

sealed trait AppliedBiIso[FAB, GAB] {
  val iso: Iso[FAB, GAB]
}
object AppliedBiIso {
  implicit def applyAndIso[FAB, GAB, Required1](
    implicit ap: ApplyBiIso.Aux[FAB, GAB, Required1],
    iso1: Required1) = new AppliedBiIso[FAB, GAB] {
    //Should do the conversion properly with Leibniz but I can't be bothered
    val iso = ap.liftBI(iso1.asInstanceOf[BiIso[ap.F, ap.G]])
  }
}

implicit def biIsoConvert[FAB, GAB](
  f: FAB)(implicit ap: AppliedBiIso[FAB, GAB]): GAB =
  ap.iso.left(f)

val map: Map[String, Int] = Map("Hello" -> 4)

val list: PairList[String, Int] =
  biIsoConvert[Map[String, Int], PairList[String, Int]](map)
```

I've no doubt it's possible to make this work correctly.

That still leaves macros, which are again a more or less orthogonal concern. One place I can see they might be relevant is that it's impossible to abstract over kind in scala without using macros. Do you want an equivalent of Iso that works for any "shape", not just `F[_, _]`? That would be a good use case for a macro - though having written this kind of macro before I don't envy anyone trying to implement it.